# RethinkDB OrderBy ignored

Tags: c#, rethinkdb

I have working RethinkDB with C# application querying for data - I have created index for one of fields but got different results when running from Web UI or C# application (using driver)

here is my query from Web UI:

```
r.db('db_data').table('table_data').orderBy({index:r.desc('my_index')}).limit(1)
```

and here is my C# code:

```
RethinkDB.R.
   Db(mSelectedDB).
   Table(mSelectedTable).
   OrderBy(RethinkDB.R.Desc("my_index")).OptArg("index", "my_index").
   Limit(1)
   Run(conn);
```

when I run from Web I correctly get **last result**, but form C# app I **get first** - so my OrderBy doesn't work, what am I doing wrong here? ATM only working solution in C# is to use Nth(-1) instead of Limit(1) + R.Desc but that is muuuuch slower so I'd prefer to avoid it.

environment: VS 2015, RethinkDb.Driver.2.3.15

Comment: Your title is misleading.  If anything, this isn't a C# language issue, it is a rethinkdb issue.  Please clarify your question, including data structure

Comment: Try `OrderBy().OptArg("index", RethinkDB.R.Desc("my_index"))` instead. Disclaimer: not tested since I didn't know anything about RethinkDB until 5 minutes ago, but I'm going by [the documentation](https://rethinkdb.com/api/java/order_by/).

Comment: tried that (no parameter), doesn't work

Comment: @DavidL this IS C# driver issue as my tests shown that Web UI with same parameters (at least I think they should work same) produce different values

Comment: @zodi exactly, it has everything to do with the driver and nothing to do with the language per se.  The point is that it isn't `.OrderBy` that is necessarily the issue but rather how you are using it in conjunction with the driver.  The update to the title helped clarify that intent.a

Comment: any news on this issue ? also have it.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly confused about the question but if you are getting the first result from an orderby and you want the last have you tried using an OrderByDescending?

```
RethinkDB.R.
Db(mSelectedDB).
Table(mSelectedTable).
OrderByDescending(RethinkDB.R.Desc("my_index")).OptArg("index", "my_index").
Limit(1)
Run(conn);
```

Comment: Sorry I would have prefered to comment on the question but I am not allowed to comment yet

Comment: there is no such method in RethinkDb.Driver.2.3.15